# How to add on text to a Javascript document.title script

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a script in Javascript that, when text is submited into a input field it changes the text in the browser tab to what is inputed into the input field. I was wondering how would you add text to this, for example if you search on google it shows the words you put into the google search bar (your query), but adds on - google search. Below is the code I used for the dynamic tab title change.

```
function changePageTitle() { 
  document.title=document.getElementById("textinput").value;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it shows the words you put into the google search bar`? Do you want the title to change as you type? If so check out the `input` event.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the script already replicates what you type in the input feild and replaces the tabs title with it. What i want to do is add on text next to what ever you typed in the input feild every time regardless of what you typed. For example: you searched (what ever you put in the input feild).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm getting is you are looking at adding additional text into the title that isn't included in what the user typed in.

If that is the case you can use basic `string concatenation` to append the string to what is typed in. You can use `+` after the value to add in additional text.

The below function update allows you to pass more text to the function and have it appended to whatever the user typed in.

```
function changePageTitle(more_text) {
  document.title = document.getElementById("textinput").value + " " + more_text;
}
```

**So you would call it like:**

```
changePageTitle("- Added FROM Input!");
```

And `- Added FROM Input!` would be added to the end of whatever the user typed in.

```js
function changePageTitle(more_text) {
  document.title = document.getElementById("textinput").value + " " + more_text;
  console.log(document.title);
}

title = document.querySelector("#textinput");
btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

title.addEventListener("input", function() {
  changePageTitle("- Added from input");
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  changePageTitle("- Added from input");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textinput">
<input type="submit" value="APPLY" id="btn">

<input type="submit" onclick="changePageTitle('- Added from input');" value="APPLY w/ onclick" id="btn">
```

Comment: How would you implement that into the html?

Comment: @Zach, just change where ever you are already calling `changePageTitle`

Comment: @imvian2 is it just onclick="changePageTitle(more_text)"? or changePageTitle()

Comment: @Zach `changePageTitle('Your text here');`

Comment: @imvian2 then what is more_text?

Comment: @Zack it is a variable that will hold whatever is passed to `changePageTitle`. So if you have `changePageTitle('ZACK')`, `more_text` will equal `ZACK`. If you have `changePageTitle('Zack Attack')` `more_text` will equal `Zack Attack` etc..

Comment: So, if im understanding correctly this is what the javascript is: `function changePageTitle('Zack Attack') {
  document.title = document.getElementById("terminalTextInput").value + " " + Zack Attack;` and this is the html `onclick="changePageTitle('Zack Attack') "`

Comment: @Zack, when you go to implement, leave the function in my answer as is. However, to help you understand what the function is doing with the passed parameter, yes that is close enough to what is happening just don't use that as it won't work.

Comment: Could you make a Jsfiddle so i can work hands on with what is correct and to see what im doing wrong?

Comment: @Zack, I updated my answer to include a working snippet. However, due to how the snippets/js fiddle works it doesn't allow you to change the title. But it will popup the console to show you what the title would be.

Comment: @Zack, I updated my answer with the right way to do it with `addeventlistener` and the outdated way of `onclick`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort put into this thread. Your edit actually worked and is found to be greatly helpful. i appreciate it.